# How to highlight multiple selections?

Tags: ace-editor

For example I have some text in ace-editor and a list of ranges of rows and lines in text where highlightings should happened. Like this (they're bolded):

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit **amet**, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. 
Morbi ut mi. Nullam enim leo, egestas id, **condimentum** at, laoreet mattis, 
massa. Sed **eleifend** nonummy diam. Praesent mauris ante, elementum et, 
bibendum at, **posuere** sit amet, nibh.*

How to highlight these words by using ace-editor API?

How to highlight multiple lines?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I've got the answer.

Highlight the word:

```
var range = new Range(rowStart, columnStart, rowEnd, columnEnd);
var marker = editor.getSession().addMarker(range,"ace_selected_word", "text");
```

Remove the highlighted word:

```
editor.getSession().removeMarker(marker);
```

Highlight the line:

```
editor.getSession().addMarker(range,"ace_active_line","background");
```